# Single selector is not being processed

Tags: html, css

I authored the *Unknown Armies* character sheet for [Roll20](http://roll20.net). The full source is available on the [Roll20 Character Sheets repository](https://github.com/Roll20/roll20-character-sheets/tree/master/UnknownArmies).

The first selector in my CSS file is:

```css
div.sheet-madness
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}
```

The VTT prepends `.charsheet` to each selector if it isn't already present in the CSS source to insure character sheets don't modify anything elsewhere on the page. It also prepends `sheet-` to each class used in the HTML source for similar reasons. When I view the page source for the VTT, as expected, I find a style element in the header which contains:

```css
.charsheet div.sheet-madness
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}
```

However, the checkboxes in the madness divisions are not lining up correctly. When I inspect the styles on the div, I get nothing at all:

[image: Code inspector]

My other selectors all seem to be working perfectly fine, including `div.sheet-madness > input[type="checkbox"].sheet-madness` and `div.sheet-madness:last-child > input[type="checkbox"].sheet-madness + span::before`. I don't understand what's wrong, why this *one* selector seems to be failing.

This problem also causes the `attr_$stress-$notchType_max` inputs to be in the completely incorrect location, as they are being absolutely positioned, and `div.sheet-madness` is their parent element, which I want the absolute positioning to be relative to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not certain *why* this is happening, however, I managed to fix it by adding a dummy selector to the top of the CSS file:

```
div.nop { }

div.sheet-madness
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}
```